# Django - List blog posts in another view

Tags: django, django-views

I have got two Models: Member and Blog whic is called MyPosts. I have got a Member Detail page which looks like a Facebook profile page and I want to list user's posts there. How can I do that?

My Member Model:

```
class Member(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='members')
member_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
member_adress = models.CharField(max_length=200)
.
.
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=140, unique=True)
etc. 

    def __str__(self):
    return self.member_name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('memberships:dashboard')

def _get_unique_slug(self):
    slug = slugify(self.member_name)
    unique_slug = slug
    num = 1
    while Member.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
        unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, num)
        num += 1
    return unique_slug

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = self._get_unique_slug()
    super().save()
```

My Blog Model:

```
class MyPosts(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=True, related_name='postcreator')
title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
content = models.TextField(max_length=240)
publishing_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=140, unique=True, blank=False, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-publishing_date', 'id']
```

My Detail Page View:

```
def MemberDetailView(request,pk, slug):
try:
    infos = Member.objects.get(pk=pk, slug=slug)
except Member.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("Member does not exist")
post_list = MyPosts.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.id) # this gives a self error


return render(request, 'directory/member-detail.html', {'memberinfo':infos}, {'memberposts':post_list} )
```

How can I add my *post view* there to see them on the same "member-detail" page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your view.

Firstly, `MemberDetailView` is a view function, not a class based view. Therefore you should use `request`, not `self.request`. You can simplify `request.user.id` to `request.user`.

Secondly, when you call render, the context should go in a single dictionary.

```
def MemberDetailView(request, pk, slug):
    try:
        infos = Member.objects.get(pk=pk, slug=slug)
    except Member.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Member does not exist")
    post_list = MyPosts.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'directory/member-detail.html', {'memberinfo':infos, 'memberposts':post_list})
```

If you want to improve the view further, I recommend renaming it to `member_detail_view` to match the PEP8 style guide for function names. You can also use `get_object_or_404` to simplify the code:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def member_detail_view(request, pk, slug):
    infos = get_object_or_404(Member, pk=pk, slug=slug)
    post_list = MyPosts.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'directory/member-detail.html', {'memberinfo':infos, 'memberposts':post_list})
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. However I keep receiving errors like "'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable" when I try  "user=request.user" . If I try user=request.user.id instead of "user" only, then I receive a blank page. I mean full of my html but no content fetched from db. I think its because I was not a logged in user. When I log in, I receive "Cannot query "xyz": Must be "Member" instance." I want my post list to be able to seen by everybody, no matter by logged in users or not

Comment: OK. it was a bit my mistake of using tags for calling my content, but ,on the other hand, I got a positive result when I choose using "MyPosts.objects.filter()" instead of filling the parenthesis. However, it shows all the posts of any users. Not only the user whose profile page I visit, not the posts to whom they belong...

Comment: If you want to show posts for the member instead of the logged-in user, then use `MyPosts.objects.filter(user=member)`. If you want to use `request.user` to filter objects, then it is often useful to use the `login_required` decorator to prevent the anonymous user error.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alasdair , I did it by using "user=pk" : 
post = MyPosts.objects.all().filter(user=pk)